# Conformance checking with pm4py

Tags: python, process-mining

Currently experimenting with PM4PY to perform conformance checking on an eventlog.
I'm facing difficulties retrieving the diagnostics as per the pm4py.algo.conformance.tokenreplay sub package. Beneath you can find my code, but in essence it is simply copy pasted out of the documentation. None of my objects are empty, they hold the correct info. Still, the outcome of this function is an empty object.

(The same issue holds for the unwanted activities etc)

Anyone out there that could help me out here?

Kind regards

```
replayed_traces, place_fitness, trans_fitness, unwanted_activities = token_based_replay.apply(log, net,
                                                                                                  initial_marking,
                                                                                                  final_marking,
                                                                                                  parameters=parameters_tbr)

from pm4py.algo.conformance.tokenreplay.diagnostics import duration_diagnostics
trans_diagnostics = duration_diagnostics.diagnose_from_trans_fitness(log=log, trans_fitness=trans_fitness)
```

Even though the code is correct, I did not retrieve the wanted diagnostics. The other functions perform as expected, letting me think that my preparation has been done correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example